# Is there an easy way to run hibernate 'dbCreate update' AFTER liquibase changesets? (Perhaps in bootstrap)

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using liquibase and grails5, and would like to run the hibernate dbCreate code (in development mode) after liquibase is finished.

If you run with with dbCreate set to update, hibernate creates/updates the database before liquibase runs.  This makes the liquibase create table statements fail (without complex preconditions).

This way in dev mode I can create new domain classes and modify them, while postponing writing the changelog until after I've got everything ironed out.

I'm assuming some magic incarnation of `SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(...)`

Here is an ancient similar question about running SchemaValidation after liquibase.
[Validate GORM model after migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16308170/3617746)

Comment: This does not answer "Is there an easy way to run the hibernate 'dbCreate update' manually from Bootstrap?" but you should be able to set `dbCreate` to `update` for only the `development` environment `DataSource`(s).

Comment: setting dbCreate to update runs things in the incorrect order.  The goal is to get Liquibase to run before hibernate tries to update the database.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find this documented anywhere, but by checking the debugger I was able to put the following code into Bootstrap after setting dbCreate to 'none' in applicaiton.yml.

I assume this will break in some mysterious ways in the future, and just downright blow up with the next hibernate upgrade.

```
 import org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore
 import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor
 import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry
 import org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator

 // injected beans
 SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory
 HibernateDatastore hibernateDatastore
 
 def init = {
     // if in dev mode...
     def metaData = hibernateDatastore.metadata
     ServiceRegistry sr = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry()
     Map m = sessionFactory.properties
     m["hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"] = "update"
     SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(metaData, sr, m, { -> })

 }
```

Comment: Is this serving some requirement that would not be served by setting `dbCreate` to `update` in your configuration of your `development` dataSource?

Comment: If you set dbCreate to update, then hibernate will update the database before liquibase does the changes.  That feels like the incorrect order.

Comment: I misunderstood.  I thought you wanted a path to get the migration out of the way and let Hibernate create the schema for you in your dev env.  Sorry that I misunderstood.